# Updating QListWidget and QtreeWidget in a QMainWindow PyQt

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, qmainwindow, qlistwidget

I have a QMainWindow that creates a QListWidget and a QTreeViewWidget and places them in a QDockWidget. I then have an "open" action in the menu bar. When clicked it gives a dialog were you choose a pickle file to load. Upon opening i need the information to be loaded into the QTreeView and QListWidget in the QMainWindow. However, since the widgets were already instantiated upon opening the program they don't update. Everything works fine if i choose a file before the program actually starts. Everything also works if i close and reopen the widgets after i choose my file. So, is there some way to update the QMainWindow to show the updated information after opening a new file?

Comment: Not a duplicate i've read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28536520/how-to-update-qlistwidget and all other related before post.