# Refresh a QListWidget after deleting elements

Tags: python, pyqt, qlistwidget

I have some trouble updating a `QListWidget`after deleting an item of it.

This is part of the code:

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
  list_1 = []  #The items are strings
  list_2 = []  #The items are strings

  def __init__(self):
    #A lot of stuff in here

  def fillLists(self):
    #I fill the lists list_1 and list_2 with this method

  def callAnotherClass(self):
    self.AnotherClass().exec_()   #I do this to open a QDialog in a new window

class AnotherClass(QDialog):
  def __init__(self):
    QDialog.__init__(self)

    self.listWidget = QListWidget()

  def fillListWidget(self):
    #I fill self.listWidget in here

  def deleteItems(self):
    item_index = self.listWidget.currentRow()
    item_selected = self.listWidget.currentItem().text()

    for index, content in enumerate(Window.list_2):
        if content == item_selected:
            del Window.list_2[index]
            break
```

After deleting the item with the `deleteItems`method, i want to see the remaining items of the list inmediately in the `QListWidget`. In other words, i need to delete the item from the list as soon as i press the button "Delete".

I have tried with `update()` and `repaint()` after the break call, but it does  not work.

How can i do this? Hope you can help me.

------------Edit---------------

The `QListWidget`is updated if i close the `QDialog`. When i open it again, i do not see the item that i deleted. So, the list is updating, but not while the `QDialog` is still open.

Comment: Frankly, you shouldn't have to call `repaint()`. Also in your code I don't see a single call of `update()` (which is what you need). If it doesn't work you can always recreate the `QListWidget` and replace (remove old and then add new) the current one with the new one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I erased the `update` line (below the `break`call) before i paste the code here. Do you mean that i may have to delete the list after the `break` call and create another one?

Comment: Okay. As for the recreation of the `QListWidget` - not really. I would suggest that you rather delete all the items you want and at the end recreate and reattach the newly generated widget. From your edit I would suggest adding a signal that is emitted whenever the list is changes and it will go into a slot in QDialog itself that will refresh it (via `update()` if it works or via recreation and reattachement of the `QListWidget`). This way the dialog will be notified of the changes. Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28540716/1559401) for some example using repaint().

Comment: I replaced the `repaint()` in that example and it works with `self.listWidget.update()` too. Just invert the behaviour (and remove the timer ;)) to see how it works.

Comment: Where did you put that line? After item_selected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are removing the item from the list that you used to populate the `QListWidget`. When you first create the `QListWidget`, a **copy** of the data is stored internally by Qt. Updating the original source will not delete the item from the `QListWidget`. However when you close and reopen the dialog, the `QListWidget` is recreated, so you see the correct data (since it is effectively reloaded from the source).

You should use [`QListWIdget.takeItem()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#takeItem) to remove the rows you want. In your case, this is:

```
item_index = self.listWidget.currentRow()
self.listWidget.takeItem(item_index)
```

You should still remove the item from your source list (`Window.list_2`) as well as per your current code.